# Android Visualizer Wtat is captureSize?

Tags: android

I cant understand 1 thing:

I set capture size with method `setCaptureSize(1024)` or `setCaptureSize(1)`
and I got byte array with 1024 length on out of `getFfft` anyway.

Is this `captureSize`? I cant understand how to use it, and that is it, help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setCaptureSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#setCaptureSize%28int%29) indicates the lenght of the byte array returned by the listener. The capture size must be a power of 2, and it indicates the "granularity" of audio capture.